# Regex Expression in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Can anyone assist me in extracting the "Test:D2D" and "NVRAM" or "YES" from the output using regex.
Something more in general.

```
$Test =@'
Lab#sh ip vrf int | i 192.168.1.1
Gi0/1.1951             192.168.1.1    Test:D2D                         up
'@

$Sample =@'
Router# show ip interface ef | i 10.108.00.5
Ethernet0     10.108.00.5    YES  NVRAM   up                      up 
'@
```

Comment: What have you tried? Be mroe specific. You can use `-match` and `$Matches` to extract values from regex-matches, or  `[regex]::match()`. Try to create your own regex using a tester like http://regex101.com  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to match those lines you can do this

```
$Test = @'
Lab#sh ip vrf int | i 192.168.1.1
Gi0/1.1951             192.168.1.1    Test:D2D                         up
'@

# this only returns strings that contain 'test:d2d'
$Test -split "`r`n" | ? {$_ -match 'test:d2d'}

$Sample = @'
Router# show ip interface ef | i 10.108.00.5
Ethernet0     10.108.00.5    YES  NVRAM   up                      up 
'@

# this only returns strings that either contain 'yes' or 'nvram'
$Sample -split "`r`n" | ? {$_ -match 'nvram|yes'}
```

but you would have more freedom to manipulate this information if you converted them to powershell objects like this

```
$Sample = @'
Router# show ip interface ef | i 10.108.00.5
Ethernet0     10.108.00.5    YES  NVRAM   up                      up 
'@ -split "`r`n" | ? {$_ -notmatch '^[a-z]+#'}

# get most number of columns we will need
$cols = $Sample | % {($_.split() | ? {$_}).count} | sort -desc | select -f 1

$Sample | % {
    $line = $_.split() | ? {$_}
    $obj = New-Object psobject
    1..$cols | % {
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Col$_ -value $line[$($_-1)]
    }
    $obj
}

$Test = @'
Lab#sh ip vrf int | i 192.168.1.1
Gi0/1.1951             192.168.1.1    Test:D2D                         up
'@ -split "`r`n" | ? {$_ -notmatch '^[a-z]+#'}

# get most number of columns we will need
$cols = $Test | % {($_.split() | ? {$_}).count} | sort -desc | select -f 1

$Test | % {
    $line = $_.split() | ? {$_}
    $obj = New-Object psobject
    1..$cols | % {
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Col$_ -value $line[$($_-1)]
    }
    $obj
}
```

for help with regular expressions, i recommend http://www.regexpal.com/ and http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Thank you Antony.You provided a more flexible solution.Its working perfect.:)